# Problems with jQuery setInterval()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-rotation

I have an image slider built with jQuery. It is set to slide image's at an interval of 7000 milliseconds. It seems, sometimes, and only sometimes, that the slider will slides the images at hyper-speed(about 1 second interval between slides). I Can't pin down the cause. Please Help!

Link to site with slider: http://healthyhometech.com

```
    function slider() {
        $(".paging").hide();
        $(".paging a:first").addClass("active");

        var imageWidth = $(".window").width();
        var imageSum = $(".image_reel img").size();
        var imageReelWidth = imageWidth * imageSum;

        $(".image_reel").css({'width' : imageReelWidth});

        rotate = function(){
            var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1; 
            var image_reelPosition = triggerID * imageWidth; 

            $(".paging a").removeClass('active'); 
            $active.addClass('active'); 

            $(".image_reel").animate({
            left: -image_reelPosition
            }, 500 );

        }; 

        rotateSwitch = function(){
            play = setInterval(function(){ 
             $active = $('.paging a.active').next(); 
                if ( $active.length === 0) { 
                $active = $('.paging a:first'); 
            }

                rotate(); 
            }, 7000); //Timer speed
        };

        rotateSwitch();

        $(".image_reel a").hover(function() {
        clearInterval(play); 
        }, function() {
        rotateSwitch(); 
        }); 


    };
```

Comment: I have not seen this bug yet, can you describe when it happens? What do yo do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a crucial problem with setInterval: it remains in memory! Therefore, chances are that you are refreshing the page while testing and, therefore, creating various setInterval for the same procedure thus, SOMETIMES, you see the procedure being execute way faster (actually, the setInterval is occurring multiple times).

I was able to solve a similar problem by using var "my-interval" = setInterval and, prior to running the setInterval, checking if it exists (not zero). If so, kill it or don't [re-]run at all:

```
var myInterval;
if (myInteval == undefined) myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    ...
    myInterval=12345;
},..);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the time value in the below section of the code:

```
$(".image_reel").animate({
        left: -image_reelPosition
        }, 500 ); //Here increase the value 500 to a value suitable to you, for example 1000, 2000 etc. anything you like.
```

The value there is in miliseconds and defines the animation speed.

[EDIT]

Ok, from what I observed, I think you get the fast sliding problem only when you leave the web page open in a tab and continue working on other tabs, then when you return to the tab containing the page, it slides the images in fast pace. if you however stay on the tab, it doesn't happen. My guess is that You noticed this problem in **Chrome** browser.

There seems to be no problem in the script, only the way the Chrome browser works. If you leave a tab in background, chrome probably pauses the setInterval() function and when you return to the page, it runs it for the amount of time it was in background. So this is probably the way Chrome browser works. No problem in the code.

Comment: Increasing or decreasing that value will increase or decrease the speed at which the picture slides, but that doesn't really solve my problem. The interval of time between the sliding animation is behaving irradically.

Comment: @user1026649 I have updated the answer, you can take a look for explanation. There seems to be no problem in the code though.